# Can I do a combination of SQL Server Basic availability groups with SQL Replication?

Tags: replication, sql-server-2016, basic-availability-groups

I need to use SQL Server Standard 2016 to keep the costs low but achieve HA. In addition we need to have two Read nodes for reporting purposes. I am wondering if I can use SQL Server Replication to get data for the two Read nodes. Is it possible to have this setup? What kind of issues this kind of setup may have down the road?

Comment: Do both read nodes need to be active simultaneously? Do they need to be 100% consistent all the time? Can you explain why you only need one node for writes but you need two nodes for reads?

Comment: The two Read nodes do need to be active simultaneously but they don't need to be consistent all the time, one can be slightly behind the other. We have a business requirement where we have two sets of users and they shouldn't be accessing the same Read node.

Comment: But why shouldn’t they be accessing the same node? Can you explain the _reason_ behind the business requirement?

Comment: I apologize for the delay in my response. We am working on getting them to use the same node. Would it be possible to have one Read node in combination with Basic Availability groups? Also, if not, is  AlwaysOn FCI with Replication to an instance outside the cluster possible? It would be ideal if all the instances are Standard 2016. Any links to these solutions would be great.